# Schwarz Derivative at $c$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can I prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then the same function is schwarz differentiable at $c$? And is the opposite true as well? My initial guess is no, but I would need a counterexample, and I'm not totally sure of one I can use.

The Schwarz derivative is defined by $$ \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac {f(c+h)-f(c-h)}{2h}. $$

Comment: There is an error here. Your expression is *independent of* $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have $f$ differentiable at $c$, then we have $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(c+h)-f(c)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(c)-f(c-h)}h=f'(c)$.  Adding the two together produces double the derivative, so we have to divide by $2$.

In the opposite direction,

$$\frac {f(c+h)-f(c-h)}{2h}=\frac {f(c+h)-f(c)+f(c)-f(c-h)}{2h}={2f'(c)\over 2}$$

However, as noted in the other answer, if $f(c)\ne \lim_{x\to c} f(x)$, then the function is not differentiable at $c$, but may be Schwarz differentiable at $c$.

Answer (score 2):

With this definition, the counter-example would be any differentiable function modified to have a jump at $c$ (so that it isn't continuous at $c$).

Comment: How is that possible?  $f$ is differentiable at $c$...  The limit $\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac {f(c+h)-f(c)}h=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac {f(c+h)-f(c)}h$ must exist for the function to be differentiable at $c$.

Comment: Take a differentiable function. Change its value at $c$.

Comment: It is a Schwarz differentiable function, which is not continuous, hence not differentiable.

Comment: I see it now, thank you.